# Can "Get Away" be used to hide?

Tags: stealth, surprise, cypher-system

Can the second tier Stealth flavour ability **Get Away** (p. 51) be used to hide, such as to allow a character to do a surprise attack each round? The text of the ability is:

> **Get Away (2 Speed points)**: After your action on your turn, you move up to a short distance or get behind or beneath cover within immediate range. Enabler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for my fellow players, but the answer is **no**.

Taking cover is an action, as stated in the Cypher System, p. 198:

> For example, if you use your dart thrower to shoot a strange floating
>   orb, that’s one action. **So is running for cover** behind a stack of
>   barrels, prying open a stuck door, using a rope to pull your friend up
>   from a pit, or activating a cypher (even if it’s stored in your pack).

To hide or sneak form an enemy is also an action (Cypher System, p. 213):

> The difficulty of sneaking by a creature is determined by its level.
>   Sneaking is a Speed roll. Moving at half speed reduces the difficulty
>   by one step. Appropriate camouflage or other gear may count as an
>   asset and decrease the difficulty, as will dim lighting conditions and
>   having plenty of things to hide behind. Being skilled in sneaking
>   reduces the difficulty of this task.

Now, **Get Away** explicitly allow to *take cover* in the same action, and since hide (or sneak) is a different action, that's not allowed.

But since a cover can be considered a *thing to hide behind*, it count as an asset if the next action is a Speed task to hide or sneak.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through this. No.

If you have already made an attack then used get away and have moved to be in cover you are no longer hidden as your target will know you are there.

And **Surprise attack** does clearly state that your opponent must be surprised for its enabler to have any effect.

P.188 of Cypher revised:

> Surprise Attack: If attacking from a **hidden vantage, with surprise, or**
>   **before your opponent has acted,** you get an asset on the attack. On a
>   successful hit, you inflict 2 additional points of damage. Enabler.

I suppose *the before your opponent has acted* leaves some ambiguity in the situation where you roll high initiative ahead of all opponents in a given round. Although this could also be interpreted in the other way for any action since the start of the encounter. As a Cypher GM I would interpret that as meaning if your opponent could be stunned or otherwise incapacitated between the start of the encounter, that way over several rounds you could conceivably get a late surprise attack in against a target.

That's not to say being in cover or well positioned using **Get away** couldn't confer an asset in its own right on potential tests. That's always a discussion between players and GM except for well defined environmental factors like being blinded etc. You just wouldn't get the 2 bonus damage **Surprise attack** gives.

The **Better surprise attack** ability P.113 of Cypher revised. has the same restrictions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100742/discussion-between-litany-and-ohmnibus).